# DIsplay a Google Sheet as HTML in Web app

Tags: pdf, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I often create and e-mail PDFs of sheets I create. But now I want to deploy a web app which will display the PDF on completion of the app.

I've tried:

```
  var gid = repSheet.getSheetId();
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+urlExt+gid, {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token} });
  blobs[0] = response.getBlob().setName('Results Report.pdf');
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(blobs[0]);
```

But I get the error that converting from PDF to HTML is unsupported.

Is it possible to simply display the Google sheet (or its) PDF on the termination of a web app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend to use an `iframe` tag to embed the preview version of the Google Sheet.

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/abcdefsddddddiwnwddwdoiwdd/preview?embedded=true"></iframe>
```

Comment: Wow. That works great. I have to adjust the size of the iframe, but that won't be hard.

Thanks.